# Xcode 4 woes. Why does a build for device immediately crash on launch?

Tags: xcode4

I am going nuts trying to figure out what Xcode 4 is complaining about when trying to build for device. This is solid, working code that builds just fine thank you under Xcode 3.2

Under Xcode 4. My code compiles, builds, installs on the device, then immediately crashes. Oddly, launching the app directly on the device works fine. WTF !?!

Here is the completely unhelpful output from Xcode 4:

[Xcode 4 build woes http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3358773/stackoverflow/xcode-woes.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3358773/stackoverflow/xcode-woes.png).

Note: I am seeing this problem with most of my working code since moving to Xcode 4.

Can someone please help me understand what Xcode 4 wants me to do here?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

That error log seems to suggest that your debugging symbols for SDK 4.2 may be missing somehow.  Do you have files under /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/ ?  If not, you might want to try reinstalling Xcode 4 and the iOS SDK.

Comment: This is a known issue with xcode4 and does not affect if an app runs or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess--but try disabling all your breakpoints (or deleting them) and see what happens. (The error message above makes me believe your problem is related in an invalid breakpoint. Perhaps Xcode got into an inconsistent state?)

Comment: He mentioned that he sees the same issue with most of his code since moving to xcode4 so this isn't project specific.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from xcode3.x to xcode4 can often lead to various problems such as this one. I had similar issues when I upgraded. Your best bet, by far, is to do a complete uninstall of xcode and reinstall clean. After doing a non-upgrade install, all my problems disappeared.

From the command line, this will completely remove your xcode:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```